# How can I duplicate all elements in an 2D array?

Tags: python

How can I duplicate all elements in an 2D array?
The order matters.

For example:

```
arr = [
  ["d", "a", "c"],
  ["b", "l", "a"],
  ["d", "u", "h"],
]

# do something

print(arr)
# Output: [
#  ["d", "d", "a", "a", "c", "c"],
#  ["b", "b", "l", "l", "a", "a"],
#  ["d", "d", "u", "u", "h", "h"],
# ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do so using list comprehension:

```
new_arr = [[element for item in sublist for element in (item, item)] for sublist in arr]
print(new_arr)
# [['d', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c'], ['b', 'b', 'l', 'l', 'a', 'a'], ['d', 'd', 'u', 'u', 'h', 'h']]
```

---

An alternative using for loops would be:

```
new_arr = []
for sublist in arr:
    new_sublist = []
    for item in sublist:
        new_sublist.extend([item, item])
    new_arr.append(new_sublist)
print(new_arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `arr` is a numpy array, you can use the `np.ravel` function for a concise version:

```
new_arr = np.ravel((arr.T,arr.T), order='F').reshape(arr.shape[0], arr.shape[1]*2)
```

Some explainer:

- [ravel](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) interleaves arrays, the order can be row-major or column-major (specified by `C` for C or `F` for FORTRAN)
- Then we need to reshape to get the correct form again, where the second axis doubled.

Comment: With `numpy` `np.repeat(arr, 2, 1)`, works with `list` and `np.array`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method using [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```py
from itertools import chain, repeat

doubled = [list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(i, 2) for i in row)) for row in arr]
```

This seems kind of overkill, but has a few nice features:

- We can easily change the repeat count to more than two
- If you don't need lists, you can iterate through this using almost no memory

Here's an example of this without converting into lists:

```py
for row in (chain.from_iterable(repeat(i, 2) for i in row) for row in arr):
   for item in row:
      # The next item hasn't been calculated yet, saving memory!
      print(item)
```